# Finding the maximum likelihood estimator (Theoretical statistics)

Tags: statistics, maximum-likelihood

Let $X_1, X_2, ..X_n$ represent a random sample from this pdf: 
$$f(x|\theta)= \frac{3x^2}{\theta^3}, 0\leq x\leq \theta$$ (with 0 elsewhere)

Could someone explain how I would find the maximum likelihood estimator (MLE) of this pdf? I know I have to get the likelihood function L, then the log likelihood function, then differentiate, but I am getting lost in the calculations. Thanks!

Comment: Please show us your workings. What I'd expect to have is that the log likelihood function is a decreasing function of $\theta$. Note that part of the likelihood function is $\log \mathbb{1}_{x \in [0,\theta]^n}$, so the maximum value must lie in $\theta \geq \max_{1 \leq i \leq n}(x_i)$.

Comment: Look at the similar question: https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3527189/

Comment: There are tons of questions here dealing with problems where support depends on parameter. Please search the site and you will find that differentiation is not the way to go.

Comment: See https://math.stackexchange.com/q/383587/321264, https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1992115/321264 for example.

Answer (score 2):

$$
\mathcal{L}(\theta; X_1,\dots, X_n) = f(X_1)\cdot\ldots\cdot f(X_n) 
$$
$$= \begin{cases}\frac{3X_1^2}{\theta^3}, & 0\leq X_1\leq \theta \cr 0, & \text{elsewhere}\end{cases}\;\times\;\ldots\;\times\; \begin{cases}\frac{3X_n^2}{\theta^3}, & 0\leq X_n\leq \theta \cr 0, & \text{elsewhere}\end{cases}
$$
$$
=\begin{cases}\frac{3^n X_1^2\cdot\ldots\cdot X_n^2}{\theta^{3n}}, & 0\leq X_1,\ldots,X_n\leq \theta \cr 0, & \text{elsewhere}\end{cases}
$$
$$
=\begin{cases}\frac{3^n X_1^2\cdot\ldots\cdot X_n^2}{\theta^{3n}}, & \max(X_1,\ldots,X_n)\leq \theta \cr 0, & \text{elsewhere}\end{cases}
$$
$$
=\begin{cases}\frac{3^n X_1^2\cdot\ldots\cdot X_n^2}{\theta^{3n}}, & \theta\geq \max(X_1,\ldots,X_n) \cr 0, & \theta< \max(X_1,\ldots,X_n) \end{cases}
$$

Since $\frac{3^nX_1^2\cdot\ldots\cdot X_n^2}{\theta^{3n}}$ decrease as $\theta$ increase, the highest value of $\mathcal{L}(\theta; X_1,\dots, X_n)$ is attained at the smallest value of $\theta$ satisfying the inequality $\theta\geq \max(X_1,\ldots,X_n)$. So, MLE  is $\hat\theta = \max(X_1,\ldots,X_n)$.