# Maximum likelihood estimation with uknown parameter

Tags: density-function, estimation, maximum-likelihood, parameter-estimation

There is given an i.i.d with this realisation: 0.481, 1.612, 1.755, 1.077. 
The common density function of the above  is:
\begin{array}{ll}  
\frac{3x^2}{\vartheta^3} & \textrm{if } 0\leq x \leq \vartheta\\
0 & \textrm{otherwise.}  \\
\end{array}
We have to determine the θ parameter with the ML estimation.
[image: ML with density function]

I know that we could use the above equation, but I can't see how could it help to solve the estimation. Or maybe should I use other technics?

Comment: So what is the likelihood of your data? Which $\theta$ maximises this? Remember that $x \le \theta$

Comment: I tried to write the given Xi values into the density function and multiply them.
So I got (173.976622/ϑ^12) for the right side. And if I am searching for maximum, then it should be equals to 0. But it isn't possible, if x <= ϑ. Or am I wrong?

Comment: "We have to determine the $\theta$ parameter", do you mean $\vartheta$?

Comment: @RahulMadhavan Yes.

Comment: The density functions implies the likelihood is $0$ if $x > \theta$.  So $\theta=0$ would give a zero likelihood, which is not the maximum.  So too with this data would $\theta=1$.  Meanwhile $\theta=2$ would give a positive likelihood of $(173.976622/2^{12})$, though not the maximum.

Comment: Search the site please. https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3535797/321264

Answer (score 0, accepted):

\begin{align*}
Likelihood(X_i|\vartheta) &= \begin{cases}\mathbb P(X=x_i | \vartheta)&if\, x_i<\vartheta\\0& otherwise\end{cases}\\
&= \begin{cases}\frac{3x_i^2}{\vartheta^3}&if\, x_i<\vartheta\\0& otherwise\end{cases}\\
\end{align*}
Assume $\vartheta \geq max(\{x_1,\dots,x_4\})$ as we want to maximize likelihood and don't want the probabilities therefore to be 0.

---

Now we calculate the total likelihood.
\begin{align*}
Likelihood(\{X_1,\dots,X_4\}|\vartheta) &= \sum\limits_{i=1}^4 \mathbb P(X=x_i | \vartheta)\\
&=\frac{3\left(\sum\limits_{i=1}^4 x_i^2\right)}{\vartheta^3}
\end{align*}

---

For maximizing likelihood, we set the derivative equal to 0 (to check for maxima of the function)
\begin{align*}
Likelihood(X_i|\vartheta^*) &= 0\\
-3\frac{3\left(\sum\limits_{i=1}^4 x_i^2\right)}{\vartheta^4}=0
\end{align*}
But clearly the likelihood is always decreasing with increasing $\vartheta$ as the derivative is always negative (for $\vartheta \geq max(\{x_1,\dots,x_4\})$). Therefore we set it to the lowest possibile value where all the probabilities are positive.

$$\vartheta = max(\{x_1,\dots,x_4\}) = 1.755$$